# Dispatch Action with Observable Value

Tags: rxjs, ngrx

I often find myself using the following code:

```
export class Component implements OnDestroy {

  private subscription: Subscription;

  user: string;

  constructor(private store: UserStore) {
    this.subscription = store.select(fromUsers.getUser)
      .subscribe(user => this.user = user);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  logout(): void {
    this.store.dispatch({
      type: LOGOUT,
      payload: {
        user: this.user
      }
    })
  }
}
```

As you can see I need to store the user string as a member within the component to send it with my payload.

I would rather use the user string as an observable and make use of the async pipe.

How do I need to change my code to leverage the observable of the user when dispatching the action without storing it in a member variable?

Comment: There is no connection between user logout action and user from store . You should not/ can not  connect them in my opinion .

Comment: Can you explain why is there no connection? The logout does not work without a user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ngrx effects and enhance the LOGOUT command with current user.

```
@Effect() logoutEffect$ = this.actions$
  .ofType(LOGOUT)
  .withLatestFrom(this.store$)
  .map(([action: Action, storeState: AppState]) => {
     return storeState.getUser;
   })
  .map(payload => ({type: 'LOGOUT_USER', payload}))
```

Comment: Thanks this works and I will accept this as answer. I thought about this approach as well but I did not considered it as the actions payload is not representing the state when it was dispatched. This could lead to problems where I want to replay or undo actions as the state is being fetched from the effect and is not represented in the action itself.